# Select columns from joined tables, group or distinct by a single column, and order by another column

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, order-by, distinct

Here's essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT 
    deals.*, 
    retailers.title AS retailer_title, 
    ST_Distance(retailers.lonlat, 'SRID=4326;POINT(-118.4104684 34.1030032)' :: geography, 15 * 1609.34) AS distance 
FROM deals,
INNER JOIN deal_retailers ON deal_retailers.deal_id = deals.id
INNER JOIN retailers ON retailers.id = deal_retailers.retailer_id
WHERE retailers.status = 2
GROUP BY deals.id
ORDER BY deals.discount_percent
```

I can't seem to find any combination of sub queries or window functions where I can meet all the goals: get the distance/title, only show one row per deal id, and order by deals.discount percent

I'm definitely not fully understanding how the group/distinct/joins all work together. I'm on Postgres 14 if that makes any difference

Comment: You might be looking for `distinct on (...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that gives me distinct, but then I have to sort by id instead of by discount_percent

Comment: You can still sort by discount_percent: `order by id, discount_percent`

Comment: Which one row per deal id do you want to show?

Comment: You can have multiple ORDER BYs.  `select * from (select distinct on ... ORDER BY colA, colZ desc) foo order by colB`

Comment: @jjanes I can do multiple orders, but it isn't actually ordered by discount_percent because id has to be the first order

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can do multiple orders, but it isn't actually ordered by discount_percent because id has to be the first order

Comment: @jjanes for each deal id, I would want the retailer with the shortest distance

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)